# Can't get a real value of screen width on my phone

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, media

I use `@media screen and (max-width: 600)` on my site. But my iPhone doesn't react on it. He displays full site like my desktop browser does. I added this snippet of code:

```
alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
alert(window.innerWidth);
```

When I go to the site via my desktop browser, it shows actual width of my window. But when I do it via my iPhone, it always says that screen's width is 980, both of the alerts. Why does it happen? What of `@media` can I use to make my site responsible, because `(max-width)` and `(width)` dont work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

This helped me.